# Wordpress Block Development in theme or plugins?

Tags: wordpress, components, block

I‘m a little confused by the latest trends in wordpress.

Let‘s assume I want to create a WordPress website for a company based on the components I designed.

My approach would ne creating a custom theme with the components represented by blocks. But I also heard that blocks should ne included via a plugin. But since 5.9 there is also „block theme“.

Maybe someone can help me understand the best concept for WordPress modern development.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you got an answer for this?

Comment: @Suisse no - sorry..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117075/how-to-create-a-plugin-or-block-that-can-manipulate-wordpress-dom-in-fronten

Comment: Since WP v. 6.2, there are no custom themes without blocks, all themes have a block around everything so you can edit the FULL SITE. Here is a great way to start a new block-based theme:  https://learn.wordpress.org/tutorial/streamline-your-block-theme-development-with-create-block-theme/.  Best wishes.